# Checking scanf input

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to make a software that checks whether numbers are positive or negative. If the given input is not 6 numbers it should go into error.
The thing is if I print more than 6 numbers the software just takes the first 6. I want it to go into error. What can I do?

I have yet to learn loops and am only allowed to use stdio.h.

```
int a, b, c, d, e, f;
int check;
unsigned int positive = 0;
unsigned int negetive = 0;
printf("Please insert 6 numbes\n");

check = scanf(" %d %d %d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e, &f);
printf("%d\n", check);

if (check != 6 ) { printf("Error, please try again."); }

else {
    if (a > 0) { positive = positive++ ; }
    else if (a < 0) { negetive = negetive++ ; };

    if (b > 0) { positive = positive++; }
    else if (b < 0) { negetive = negetive++; }

    if (c > 0) { positive = positive++; }
    else if (c < 0) { negetive = negetive++; };

    if (d > 0) { positive = positive++; }
    else if (d < 0) { negetive = negetive++; };

    if (e > 0) { positive = positive++; }  
    else if (e < 0) { negetive = negetive + 1; };

    if (f > 0) { positive = positive++; }
    else if (f < 0) { negetive = negetive++; };

    printf("There were %d positive numbers and %d negetive numbers", positive, negetive);

}
}
```

Comment: Please note that `positive = positive++;` is *undefined behaviour*. I suggest either `positive = positive + 1;` or `positive += 1;` or `positive++;`

Comment: when I do positive++; it changes the value to +1 automatically?

Comment: `positive++` increments the value of `positive` at *some time* between reading its value and the next sequence point. So putting `positive = positive++;` it isn't defined what happens to `positive`.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes you intended to ask "if I **enter** more than 6 numbers".

It is easier to process (and reject) input if you read the whole line with `fgets()` and then examine it. This example uses `sscanf()` to extract the values. It attempts   to scan 7 values, but accepts exactly 6.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a, b, c, d, e, f, g;
    char buffer[100];
    printf("Please insert 6 numbers\n");
    if(fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) == NULL)
        return 1;
    if(sscanf(buffer, "%d %d %d %d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e, &f, &g) != 6)
        return 1;
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d\n", a, b, c, d, e, f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if(fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) == NULL)
in this expression, what are you doing? If fgets gets no value you return 1?

Comment: It's just a short-cut, skipping the detail. If `fgets()` fails, it returns `NULL`. I didn't provide a full solution to the task, but showed how to get exactly 6 entries, which is what the question asked. If there are exactly six entries, the program prints them, otherwise nothing. There is more detail in the comments above.